# Generating a list of unique numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a list of numpy ndarrays, similar to the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> b = 3*[np.copy(a)]
>>> print b
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

But each element of this list is an alias of the original array `np.copy(a)`, so changing one element of any ndarray changes all of the other corresponding elements, ie:

```
>>> b[0][0] = 0
>>> print b
[array([0, 2, 3]), array([0, 2, 3]), array([0, 2, 3])]
```

How can I make each of these arrays independent of each other, so that the above result would be:

```
[array([0, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `3*[np.copy(a)]` actually does one copy of `a` and creates 3 references to this copy, so that you can not change only one because they are the same object. Doing this:

```
b = [np.copy(a) for i in range(3)]
```

will create 3 independent copies.

But it seems you should work with b as a 2D array, which you can achieve doing:

```
b = np.vstack((a for i in range(3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why what you were trying didn't work is that

```
>>> b = 3*[np.copy(a)]
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
>>> c = np.copy(a)
>>> b = 3*[c]
```

In Python, `c` is not the array, `c` is, in this case, a reference to an array. `3*[c]` just copies that reference three times. You could do,

```
>>> b = [np.copy(a) for i in xrange(3)]
```

as [sgpc mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198913/400793), or you could even do,

```
>>> b = [np.array([1,2,3]) for i in xrange(3)]
```

Comment: good job expanding the original statement and including the explanation.